# Tools for Version control for Xcode

Tags: iphone, xcode, version-control, osx-leopard

For my iPhone App I want to Use version Control for Xcode

so Can anyone please suggest me some user friendly tools for that  which help me to configure version control for Xcode

Please Help and Suggest,
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Xcode 3.x includes built-in support for Subversion. You may find that the developer previews of Xcode 4 also include Git support.

Xcode 3.x SVN support is configured via the "SCM" tab in the application's Preferences dialog. Xcode 4 is under NDA still, so you'll have to figure out how to do it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

I personally use http://versionsapp.com/ rather than relying on what Apple supplies in the 3.x versions of xCode

You can find some Apple documentation here http://developer.apple.com/tools/subversionxcode.html